# Writing for 2-3 different audiences at the same time - Approach?

Tags: technique, organization

For a non-fiction book ... Inside every chapter, I need to address 3 separate "audiences" (sort of)... and I am having trouble organizing this in a way that makes sense.

Here's an example : Let's say I was writing a book about providing (and receiving) the best cancer treatment in the 21st century.  So I need to write for a) patients, b) doctors  (and its important that they understand each other's issues  and then c) for hospitals - that deal with many patients and doctors and broader issues. So in each chapter/topic, I need to write 3 separate sections.

Well this approach is vexing. Now then - putting aside the knee jerk advice about either writing 3 different books, or just writing to one audience - what *would* be some approaches to organizing the book, each chapter, so this works for the 3 audiences?

Right now, I just introduce the chapter subject, and then break it up into 3 sections for the same topic- but for each of the 3 "audiences". It feels a little clunky, so I am looking for alternative techniques.

Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you could flip it around, and split the book itself into 3 sections - one for each audience? (Part I: Information for Patients, Part II: Information for Doctors, and Part III: Information for Hospitals.) You could organize the chapters within each part the same way. Of course, this might be the same problem in that you're again writing 3 different books!

Comment: If you really are talking healthcare, not just an example, then direct the book to doctors primarily, as a patient will look to their doc, and doctors and what they want drive hospital decisions. Then, include data that deals with hospital and patient concerns, since they are relevant to all these groups.

Comment: the healthcare topic was just an example - not the real topic ...

Comment: @Sciborg - well ... there are 2 "obvious" ways: your suggestion - which is to divide the book into 3 parts, or inside each chapter (which focuses on a particular topic) and divide that into 3 sections. I was hoping for other options or ideas.

Comment: How much common is the information targeted at different audiences? In your healthcare example it looks like there should be 3 different books. But in other examples (like "astronomy for the readers of all ages"), the information is the same, but should be delivered differently.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet will be to write the book explaining the commonalities (i.e., best practices), with callouts for the audience segment-specific info.

That way, you're writing just ONE book, but presenting additional and different layers of interest.

Comment: I think this is the best advice --I've seen this done successfully

Comment: Thanks. I am sort of doing that approach ... I am just not happy with the way it is turning out, thus fishing for other options or ideas. Actually I would love it if anyone had recommendations of any books that achieves this effect.